# How to generate PDF files from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having a hard time finding a solution on how to generate PDF files from SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have an existing template where the PDF I want to generate will look exactly the same with my template. But I really don't have an idea on how to start doing this.

I already downloaded a *reportviewer* because someone told me to use this. By the way, I am using C#.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This may be a help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426346/how-to-produce-documents-docx-or-pdf-from-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [SSRS](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/SQL-Server-2012-reporting-services.aspx) where exports to versatile documentsformats is supported, pdf included.